# How to update docker container after code change in ASP.net MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker

I have a existed pure asp.net mvc project.

I follow the official tutorial to put it into a container (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc#comments-container).

I wonders: how can I update the docker container if I change the code in the project? Do I need to go through the whole process (publish -> build -> start) every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to rebuild the image and start a new container.  Don't forget to `docker rm` the old container (it will be tied to the old image).  Re-running `docker build` is intended to be pretty quick, and that should be doubly true with the Dockerfile recommended on that page (that just has a COPY for the built application).